# Date Picker does not show in Infopath Form services for one user only

Tags: infopath, forms-services, datepicker

I have an Infopath form which renders in the web browser. This form was created using Infopath 2007 and published to a document library in a Sharepoint 2007 site. The field "Open Date" is a date field which can be controlled by a date picker or by manually typing the date.  However for only one specific user the date picker is not visible.  This happens in both IE8 and Firefox 3.6.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: was field added later, and does the user have the latest template installed locally?

Comment: Does the field have any conditional formatting? Does the user see the same View as other users? (silly questions, but sometimes it works)

Comment: Does the user see the calendar "button" that can be clicked to open the date picker? Or does that user not even see this part as well?

Answer (score 1):

Let this user use another user's computer to try again.

If the issue still exists, then try to check this user's permissions and your InfoPath Form's design to make sure there are no restricts to him/her.

If the issue was gone, then, you need to check this user's computer to repair or re-install some software like Office InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

Repair the Office installation on that user's machine.